# Postmaster Issues

Tags: postmaster

I recently purchased postmaster and unable to create a new parcel, when I try to save a parcel it loads the EE control panel home page.

EE 2.5.2
Postmaster 1.2.0

I also woud like to not that the  "preview" pans, loads my control panel home page too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be related to how your site directory is setup relative to where you are accessing the CP from - [see this support thread on devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/postmaster/viewthread/8324). Justin claims he'll be fixing this in a future release.

Comment: Spot on, i was just coming back to the original post to say I think it has to do with the ACT url. Hopefully he can give at least a quick fix for this, or a full release with the fox soon.

Thanks Derek.

Comment: Thanks for report. No worries, I will get a fix. Had about 1000 things to do the past couple weeks, and been chipping at the list fast as I can.